# Select Multiple OpportunityLineItems in standard listview and pass those ids to vf page

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

I have a list view button on Opportunity Line Items related list. I want to select multiple opp line items and then pass those ids to a visualforce page. StandardSetController does not work for opportunity line items. Please tell me what could be the possible ways to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is anything that blocks this for your case, but generally you can pass the ID values to your Visualforce page by adding a “List Button” with “Display Checkboxes” checked that has behavior “Execute JavaScript” and content source “OnClickJavaScript”:

```
var ids = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem)};
if (ids.length) {
    if (ids.length <= 100) {
        window.location = '/apex/YourVisualforcePage?ids=' + ids.join(',');
    } else {
        alert('Select 100 or less');
    }
} else {
    alert('Select one or more Products');
}
```

Your controller can then access these using code such as this:

```
public String[] ids {
    get {
        if (ids == null) {
            String s = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ids');
            ids = s != null ? s.split(',') : new String[] {};
        }
        return ids;
    }
    private set;
}
```

A bit more information here - [How to pass a large number of selections from a standard list view to a Visualforce page](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/how-to-pass-a-large-number-of-selections-from-a-standard-list-view-to-a-visualforce-page/).